# Using JavaScript, how can I filter an array of objects using multiple criteria in a child object

Tags: javascript

I want to get all the customers who have returned product "2":

```js
// Note that in production this array is much longer
const customers = [
  {
    "customerId": "1",
    "products": [
      {
        "productId": "1",
        "status": "purchased"
      },
      {
        "productId": "2",
        "status": "purchased"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "customerId": "2",
    "products": [
      {
        "productId": "1",
        "status": "purchased"
      },
      {
        "productId": "2",
        "status": "returned"
      }
    ],
  }
]
const returns = customers.filter((customer) =>
  customer.products.some((product) => product.productId === "2" && product.status === "returned")
);
console.log(returns);
```

I thought my use of `filter` would work - but I am guessing some() doesn't work with multiple criteria? Or am I doing something else wrong? Or is there a better way?

Comment: what exactly was the problem? i tried to reproduce, but it works fine for me on **v12.18.3**

Comment: @gregg I've made your code runnable without making *any* changes to it, and it seems to work exactly as you desire - can you clarify what's wrong with the result?

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine, has no problems and works. If it doesn't work for you, the you're doing something else wrong, somewhere else in your code, that we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition `product.productId === "2" && product.status === "returned"` does match only one object

if the productId is '2' **AND** the status is 'returned' matches the last object which is returned.

if you only want the products that have the Id of '2' then it should be `product.productId === "2"`

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score -1):

Try using **some** function for the products.

```js
const customers = [{
    "customerId": "1",
    "products": [{
        "productId": "1",
        "status": "purchased"
      },
      {
        "productId": "2",
        "status": "purchased"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "customerId": "2",
    "products": [{
        "productId": "1",
        "status": "purchased"
      },
      {
        "productId": "2",
        "status": "returned"
      }
    ],
  }
]

const returns = customers.filter((customer) =>
  customer.products.some((product) => product.productId === "2" && product.status === "returned"))

console.log(returns);
```

Comment: `arr.filter(condition).length > 0` is just a less performant way of saying `arr.some(condition)`.